# If statement works outside of script but not inside for Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've searched and searched, but nothing I find is helping. I'm very new to PowerShell and scripting in general.

I've written a script that is controlled by task scheduler to capture installed software, current logged user, etc.

The script works well, but when no one is logged in its capturing a blank for the user, which is causing issues later when I compile them all together and then try to remove all the baseline software I don't need for my reports.
So I have tried adding an `if` statement to check if a user is currently logged in. If not, it captures the last modified user folder.

The `if` statement works when I run it in the console, but only captures the currently logged user if I run it inside the script. Feel free to pick it apart. As I said I'm new to this.

```
$timeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
$directoryPath = "C:\HRC\SoftwareScans"
$file = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_$($timeStamp).csv"
$filePath = "$directoryPath\$file"

try
    {
    If(!(Test-Path -Path $filePath))
        {
        New-Item -Path $directoryPath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
        }
    # Checks current logged on user and stores it. If noone logged on it pulls last updated User folder
    # This is currently not working on computers with no one logged on
    If(!($UserTest = (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username)){
        $User = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -first 1}
    else {
        $User = (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username}
    # Checks to ensure scan file exists. If not, runs scan
    If(!(Test-Path -Path $filePath))
        {
        Get-CimInstance -Query "select * from SMS_InstalledSoftware" -Namespace 'Root\cimv2\sms' | Select-Object Publisher, ProductName, ProductVersion, @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, @{Name='User';Expression={$User.split("\")[1]}}, @{Name='ScanDate';Expression={$timeStamp}} | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    # Checks scan file for last write time. If less than a day old it doesn't scan.
    if(Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath\*.csv | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)})
        {
        Remove-Item -Path $directoryPath\*.csv
        Get-CimInstance -Query "select * from SMS_InstalledSoftware" -Namespace 'Root\cimv2\sms' | Select-Object Publisher, ProductName, ProductVersion, @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, @{Name='User';Expression={$User.split("\")[1]}}, @{Name='ScanDate';Expression={$timeStamp}} | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
        } 
    }
catch
{
    $Error.exception.message | Out-File $directoryPath\Errorslog_$($timestamp).log
}
```

Comment: That code is very hard to read due to the long lines. Please add some line breaks (you can break after `|` and `,` for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$timeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")

$directoryPath = "C:\HRC\SoftwareScans"

$file = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_$($timeStamp).csv"

$filePath = "$directoryPath\$file"



try

    {

$TestPath = Test-Path -Path $filePath

    If(!$TestPath)

        {

        New-Item -Path $directoryPath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null;

        }

    # Checks current logged on user and stores it. If noone logged on it pulls last updated User folder

    # This is currently not working on computers with no one logged on

$User = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty Username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

    If(!$User){

        $User = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -first 1}

        Get-CimInstance -Query "select * from SMS_InstalledSoftware" -Namespace 'Root\cimv2\sms' |
        Select-Object Publisher, ProductName, ProductVersion, @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, @{Name='User';Expression={$User.split("\")[1]}}, @{Name='ScanDate';Expression={$timeStamp}} | 
        Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Append


    # Checks scan file for last write time. If less than a day old it doesn't scan.

    if(Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath\*.csv | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)})

        {

        Remove-Item -Path $directoryPath\*.csv

        Get-CimInstance -Query "select * from SMS_InstalledSoftware" -Namespace 'Root\cimv2\sms' | 

        Select-Object Publisher, ProductName, ProductVersion, @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, @{Name='User';Expression={$User.split("\")[1]}}, @{Name='ScanDate';Expression={$timeStamp}} | 

        Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Append

        } 

    }

catch

{

    $Error.exception.message | Out-File $directoryPath\Errorslog_$($timestamp).log

}
```

Please note, some of the code is redundant and not needed so I modified it.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Getting the user is the main issue I'm having.

Comment: can you try it now?

Comment: That did it and makes way more sense than what I was doing. Thanks Abraham